# How to represent a set of entities from separate tables?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling, normalization

I have a few tables representing geographical entities (`CITIES`, `COUNTIES`, `ZIPCODES`, `STATES`, `COUNTRIES`, etc).

I need to way represent sets of geographical entities. A set can contain records from more than one table. For example, one set may contain 3 records from `CITIES`, 1 record from `COUNTIES` and 4 from `COUNTRIES`.

Here are two possible solutions:

- A table which contains three columns - one record for each entity. The table will contain multiple records for each set, all sharing the the set number.

> `set_id INT, foreign_table VARTEXT(255), foreign_id INT`
>
> Sample entries for set #5:
>
> `(5,'CITIES',4)`
>
> `(5,'CITIES',12)`
>
> `(5,'ZIPCODES',91)`
>
> `(5,'ZIPCODES',92)`
>
> `(5,'COUNTRIES',15)`

- A table which contains a TEXT column for each entity type, which will include a string set with the appropriate entries:

> `set_id INT,cities TEXT,counties TEXT,zipcodes TEXT,states TEXT,countries TEXT`
>
> So the above set will be represented with a single record
>
> `(5,'4,12','','91,92','','15')`

Any other ideas? Would love to hear your input.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions you propose don't have real foreign keys.  In the first solution, one foreign_id can point to many tables, which is hard (or at least inefficient) for a database to enforce.  The second solution stores multiple values in one column, which is the one thing everyone agrees you shouldn't do (it breaks [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).)

What I would do is this: cities, zip codes, and states all "have a" geographical location.  The normal way to implement that is a one to many relation.  Create a geolocation table, and add a geolocation_id column to the cities, zip code, and state tables.

EDIT: Per your comment, to get from a geolocation to its cities:

```
select    *
from      geolocation g
left join cities c
on        g.id = c.geolocation_id
left join zipcodes z
on        g.id = z.geolocation_id
....
```

The database will resolve the joins using the foreign key index, which is very fast.

Comment: Thanks! 
But now, given a geolocation_id, how do I trace it back to the correct table? One way will be to add a foreign_id/foreign_table entries to the geolocation table, but then we're back to square one. Or are you suggesting a query with multiple joins? Is that efficient? Thanks again!

Comment: @bosh: Right, you'd use a query with multiple joins.  As long as you define foreign keys, that's a very efficient operation!

Answer (score 2):

- One `Location Set` can have many `Geography` items
- One `Geography` item can belong to many `Location Sets`

Regarding the `Geography` item table, two approaches are possible. In the first case the super-type/subtype relationship is overlapping -- more than one sub-type can be linked to the super-type.
For example, there can be `GeographyID = 5` in `Geography` and `Zipcodes, Cities, States, Countries` tables.

[image: geography_model_01]

In the second case, we can consider the exclusive (disjoint) relationship, in which only one subtype can be connected to the super-type. The parent-child relationship is used to create paths, like `ZIP/City/State/Country` -- that is if actual administrative areas allow for this type of relationship.

In this example, there can be `GeographyID = 5` in the `Geography` and only one more sub-type table.

[image: geography_model_02]